# app runs on simulator but doesn't show screen objects on

Tags: xcode, simulator

I have an iPhone app running properly in the simulator. Opening screen is a table with images and text in each cell. When I attach the iPod Touch (I have provisioned it), the table appears with the correct heading on the navigation bar, and divisions between the cells, but no cell content.

The program hasn't crashed, though, (the table scrolls) but sits displaying nothing until I kill it, at which time console shows program ending with exit code: 0.

Any ideas?

(Scheme shows iPod touch).

Comment: Have you tried a Product > Clean, and a Product > Clean Build Folder (option click)?

Comment: Thanks, MattyG. I tried it and still just see the first screen, correct color, lines across the table, correct title on nav.bar, but no data in the table. When I go to Organizer - iPod touch -- it has a little message under Software Version saying Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version (5.0.1). There is a Restore iPod button beside it but I'm hesitant to use it. Will it erase the stuff on (my wife's) iPod?

Comment: I'm not sure what the Xcode > Organizer > Devices - Restore does sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the question. Here it is for anyone else who lands here with the same problem:

The table was populated by taking data from a file called "Data.plist" in the Resources group. My code said, "data.plist". It ran in the simulator because the simulator runs OSX which is NOT case sensitive. The device runs iOS which IS case sensitive.